# css mask-image alternative for ie to create editable svg background color

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to use svg **as file** and use it in css and I have to change it's color when I hover it.

I can create this very simple with **mask-image** css property

```
.icon {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(icon.svg);
    mask-image: url(icon.svg);
}
```

But this method is not working in ie (any versions) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image

I don't want to use svg **as code**, It's not looking good.

Is there any way to use svg like this?

Ps: I know I can add it as img element in html and a bit js can handle this img to edit svg color but I want to use it as background-image.

Comment: Have two images and change from one to the other on hover.

Comment: Or have both colours in one SVG (ie. an SVG sprite sheet) and change the `background-position` on hover.

Comment: This method sounds good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the svg into a font and then use the font on the .icon element. 
Then you could just change the color attribute.